# JUnit test for Timer class java 1.4

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a JUnit test for testing some function in which I am using a time class from java 1.4. What this test case does is create a file and that file will be passed a parameter to the function which I am testing. My method is using `timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay);` to remove that file. My test case is running but it doesnt wait for the delay passwed to `timer.schedule()`. My code example is as follows.

Function to test:

```
public void clean(String fileName){

    long delay = 1000 * 60;
    timer = new Timer();

    final File f= new File(fileName);
    if(!f.exists()){
        f.createNewFile();      
    }

            timer.schedule(new RemoveFile(f), delay);  

            //RemoveFile() is inner class which extends
            TimerTask and remove the file. TimerTask is 
            an abstract class that implements
            Runnable interface.

}
```

My TestCase is as follows

```
public void testClean(){

         String file = "c:\\Users\\abc\\abc.txt";       
         Cleaner instance = Cleaner.getInstace(); //Static method
         instance.clean(file);

}
```

This testcase doesnt wait for the TimerTask to complete its function. I dont know how to put some wait that the testcase wait for the TimeTask thread to finish its work.

Comment: You could add a parameter to `getInstance()` that will set the delay period. Then, for testing, you can supply `0`. This could be a package-private method. It depends what you consider important to test about this method.

Comment: If you are planning to wait for the the background thread to delete the file after you call the clean method, why aren't you deleting the file in your thread instead? + What kind of test is this? Where do you assert that the clean method actually did its job?

Comment: @Duncan: I understand your solution and I have already tested it. It works fine with 0 delay but actually I would like to understand how to put wait in JUnit tests.

Comment: @shlomi33: No the file must be deleted in a separate thread. I dont want to put main thread to wait.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Have you tried `Thread.sleep(60000)`?

Comment: @Duncan: this is same solution as set delay 0 :). Can we use something like thread.notify() ? my main thread wait until this file deletion thread notify it to continue execution ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I'm confused, are we fixing your test here or your actual code? I had assumed the purpose of your test was to wait 60s and confirm it had deleted the file. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Duncan: I want that testCase should be independent of whatever the delay is. It waits until the new thread deletes the file and notify this main thread that I have done my work now continue execution.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I don't think you'll find an easier approach than allowing the test case to define the delay. I don't really see a downside to that approach.

Comment: @Duncan: yes I know there is nothing wrong to add delay in testcase. Thank you verymuch for your help.